# AWS TransferManager Uploads using a Signed Policy

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**Environment**

---

1. Windows OS
2. Android SDK
3. AWS SDK for Android
4. Android Studio

**Use-case**

---

A user captures video on his SmartPhone and uploads to S3 cloud storage

**Requirements**

---

1. Use chunked upload
2. Implement as an app and not as a website
3. Avoid using the "Secret Key" on the SmartPhone app, rather use a [signed policy ~document~](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434)
4. Implement using [TransferManager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html)

**Problem at hand**

---

[Browser-Based Upload using HTTP POST](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) supports usage of a policy signed by the server with the "Secret Key", and thus, keep the "Secret Key" on the server.
The [TransferManager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html) requires to provide the "Secret Key" to accomplish the upload.

Having the "Secret Key" On the user SmartPhone app is a security hole and should be avoided.

**Is there any way to have The [TransferManager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html) use the same policy concept introduced with [Browser-Based Upload using HTTP POST](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) ( or another ) where the "Secret Key" is kept at bay ?**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: While not strictly an answer to your question, you can use the token vending machine to deliver credentials to your app and use those credentials with the TransferManager. See [our blog](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx371Y7CA0QJ95X/Simplifying-Token-Vending-Machine-Deployment-with-AWS-CloudFormation) for a simple guide to deploying a TVM for your use.

Comment: Is this still the recommended approach? We have a web app using signed policies for uploads (obtained from the api after authentication) and are developing an Android app, This is a bit of a bummer :(